# How to format a AAAAMMDD in date AAAA-MM-DD IN R?

Tags: r, date

I have a column with date in the format 20201020 (AAAAMMDD) as integer and a need to format as date 2020-10-20.

I`ve tried:

```
as.Date(MYDATE, format = "%m/%d/%y", origin = "1900-01-01")
```

AND

```
format(MYDATE, "%m/%d/%Y")
```

But returned just

```
NA
```

Answer (score 0):

Using *lubridate* we can:

```
ymd(MY_DATE)
```